# fetch user custom fields in article

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field

I have created some custom fields in user profile from backend

```
templates/name-template/html/com_content/article/default.php
```

and use this code for load custom fields at joomla article

```
<?php 
$context = 'com_content.article';
$article = $this->item;

//use the field helper class to get the fields
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields($context, $article, true);
// Added so as to access fields by their name

// GET CUSTOM FIELDS
foreach($fields as $field) {
    $fields[$field->name] = $field;
}
?>
```

and use this code for fetch

```
<?php echo ($fields['name-field']->value); ?>
```

i creat textarea fileds at user profile for write about me (author)
[image]
now I want to fetch users custom fields (author) in joomla article
How can i do it ؟

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change context to `com_users.user` and the item to article author's user object. Since some articles may not have an author, this code should be wrapped in author check:

```
// Only run if article has an author.
if ($this->item->created_by)
{
    // Get author's custom fields.
    $fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', JFactory::getUser($this->item->created_by), true);

    // Display fields here.
}
```